# How to pull YTD with xpath from this site?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

I'm importing data from etf.com to my Google Sheets. For the VTI ETF I want
pull the "YTD" element.

Chrome inspection says that I should use the following

```
xpath=IMPORTXML("http://www.etf.com/VTI","//*[@id='form-reports-overview']/div[1]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]")
```

This returns nothing though.

However I can extract most of the other fields just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try either:

```
=index(IMPORTXML("http://www.etf.com/VTI","//td[@class='col4']"),1,1)*100&"%"
```

or:

```
=index(importhtml("http://www.etf.com/VTI","table",5),2,4)*100&"%"
```